# On a "distance" measure between a normal random vector and a hyperplane

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

Let $\mathcal{H}\colon\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}+b=0$ denote a hyperplane in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Omega_{\pm}=\{\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb{R}^n\colon\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}+b\gtrless0\}$ be the positive and negative halfspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$ with respect to $\mathcal{H}$.

Also, let $d\colon\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ be a function with 
$$
d(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}+b.
$$

I use $d$ as a (signed) "distance" function so as to characterize an arbitrary point $\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb{R}^n$ about its relative position with respect to the hyperplane $\mathcal{H}$. More specifically, I want $d$ to increase as the point goes deeper in the positive halfspace and to decrease as the point goes deeper in the negative halfspace. $d$ does a good job for this purpose. A $2$D example is shown below.

[image: The "distance" function $d$ evaluated on a point $\mathbf{x}$.]

Now, let's assume that $\mathbf{x}$ is a normal random vector with mean $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. A $2$D example is shown below. The ellipse denotes an iso-density locus that encloses points with density greater that a certain value. We use this just for illustration purposes.

[image]

For computing a similar "distance" measure that fulfill the above criterion, one could compute the expected value of $d(\mathbf{x})$, which is given by $d(\bar{\mathbf{x}})=\mathbf{w}^\top\bar{\mathbf{x}}+b$. This would give a good answer since the ellipse is entirely inside the one (positive in this case) halfspace, but what about the following example?

[image]

Intuitively, I would expect the computed "distance" measure to be less than the one computed in the previous example, since there is a part of the ellipse that belongs to the opposite halfspace, but using just the mean operator, these values will be the same.

Of course, taking the expected distance do encapsulate the fact there are also values of the random vector in the negative halfspace, but I think that the knowledge of the variance could also be used for arriving at a more meaningful "distance" measure.

Let's take for granted that I'm able to compute the expected values of $d(\mathbf{x})$ over the two halfspaces, i.e., to compute (analytically) the integrals
$$
d_{\pm} = \int_{\Omega_{\pm}}d(\mathbf{x})f(x)\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x},
$$
where $f$ is the probability density function of $\mathbf{x}$. One could note that
$$
d_+ + d_- = d(\bar{\mathbf{x}}),\quad d_+\geq0, d_-\leq0.
$$
I could use $d_{\pm}$ to "scale" $d(\bar{\mathbf{x}})$ appropriately, for instance.

What are your thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: You are interested in the distribution of the component of your random vector in the direction normal to your hyperplane.  That component has a 1 dimensional gaussian distribution, whose parameters are easy to work out.  That's all there is to it, unless you like to make simple things complicated.

Comment: @kimchilover thanks for your comment. So, you mean the random variable $y=\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}+b$? This has mean $\bar{y}=\mathbf{w}^\top\bar{\mathbf{x}}+b$ and variance $\sigma^2_y = \mathbf{w}^\top\Sigma\mathbf{w}$, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Unless you mean something totally different.

Comment: Yes, that's the one I mean.  What I don't understand is what you are asking, what *proceed* means here, what you are working towards.  It's all *one could* and *intuitively* and so on, but no actual question.  What, precisely, ---- and concisely--- do you want to do with $y$?

Comment: @kimchilover take a look at the last 2 figures: the mean "distance" will be the same for both cases. I would like to penalize that measure in the second one due to its particular "geometry" of its variance. Does that even make sense?

Comment: So in the one case the distribution of values of $y$ is tightly concentrated away from 0 and in the other it kind of slops over 0.  So what?  You want a numerical formula quantifying that?  How about $P(y\le0)$, which you can express in terms of your parameters?  It is for you to choose what you are interested in, pose a precise question about it, and -- with luck and maybe a little help -- answer that precise question.

Comment: @kimchilover Exactly, I would like a numerical formula that expresses this fact; $P(y\leq0)$ would do the job I guess. The original spirit of the question was to discuss it and figure out a precise statement and a meaningful answer. The fact that you keep commenting on this, is exactly what I was expecting; thanks for your time :) So, does the "intuition" above make sense to you? Could the distance in the second figure be less than the one in the first?

Comment: You have some application or particular problem in mind.  Maybe it already suffices to say "the centroid is 1.4 sigmas away from the hyperplane" or maybe you need a new term, the "straddling coefficient is .72".

Comment: @kimchilover That's right, I need it in a machine learning method (very hard to explain here). Such a measure (the "straddling coefficient for instance") would be nice, but how I compute it. What I thought is to compute the probability $P(y>0)$, for instance, and scale with it the "mean distance" $d(\bar{\mathbf{x}})$, since what I really want is a distance measure.